# Python: Saving formatting when creating an html output

Tags: python, html

I am running windows commands like ipconfig and trying to capture them in an html page. I am running into an issue where the formatting is not what I would want. I have a function that writes my html.

```
def writeHTML(toWrite):
    output.write("<p>")
    if toWrite.find("   ") == 1:
        toWrite.replace("   ", "&nbsp")
    output.write(toWrite)
    print(toWrite)
    output.write("</p>")
```

I have tried to "find" \t and the blank spaces but the fomatting does not work.

Preferred Output:

[image]

Current Output:

[image]

How can I maintain the formatting?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the <p> tags with <pre>? This would eliminate the need to replace spaces. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

Comment: guess you want to use something like *jinja* to format output

Comment: @peteredhead Okay, that worked! I'll just style it like the rest of the page. Thanks!

Comment: So... question answered?